# Derivative of sinc function

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that function $\left(\operatorname{sinc}{x}\right)^{n}=\left\{\dfrac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}\right\}^{n}$ is infinitely differentiable at $0$?

Comment: You only need to show it for $\frac{sin x}{x}$ itself; its powers are then $C^\infty$ because the product of two $C^\infty$ functions is itself $C^\infty$.

Comment: If your class has covered Taylor series, then you will see that $\sin x/x$ is represented by an everywhere converging Taylor series, and therefore ... The rest then follows from Henning's comment.

Comment: This http://ebooks.cambridge.org/chapter.jsf?bid=CBO9780511754661&cid=CBO9780511754661A220 maybe also helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Taylor series expansion as mentioned in the comments to get:
$$
\text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{-\sum_{k=0}^\infty { (-x)^{2k+1} \over {(2k+1)!}} }{x}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty {(-1)^{2k+1}(x)^{2k} \over {(2k+1)!}}=1-{x^2 \over 3!}+{x^4 \over 5!}-\cdots,
$$
which is infinitely often differentiable at $0$. You'll get
$$
\frac{d^m}{dx^m} \text{sinc}(x) \Biggr|_{x=0}=
\cases{
{(-1)^{m}\over(m+1)} & \text{if $m$ is even}\\
\phantom{case}&\\
\;\;\;\;\,\,0 & \text{if $m$ odd.} \\
}
$$
*Because the product of two $C^∞$ functions is itself $C^∞$*, we are done.

Comment: I don't find the argument convincing as it stands. Something important is missing. Your definition of sinc works only for x non-zero. You've only proven sinc is differentiable away from zero.